# Schema Comparison technique in Java

Tags: java, schema-compare

I am working on a web Application using Spring, Hibernate and JPA. In my application, data has to be processed in Source database and encrypted data has to be copied in Target database which is done by Masking Engine.

If the application is created and while doing the masking if database schema is changed, then it has to be handled.

Currently I am using SchemaCrawler for schema comparison. But it has significant impact on performance.

So is there any alternate solution for doing schema Comparison in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Yateen,

SchemaCrawler has a number of options that allow you to fetch only the metadata that you are interesed, thereby saving time. For example, you can look for only certain tables in certain schemas, using regular expressions. Please take a look at the javadocs for [SchemaCrawlerOptions](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/apidocs/schemacrawler/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawlerOptions.html) for more details.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I tried to use inclusion rules to get optimum result but still it is not upto the mark.
That is the reason I am looking for some alternative.

Comment: Yateen, also look at the SchemaInfoLevel, which is part of SchemaCrawlerOptions. SchemaInfoLevel settings affect the time taken to obtain database metadata. http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/apidocs/schemacrawler/schemacrawler/SchemaInfoLevel.html